# Multiple value for if-statement

Tags: c#, list

If my statement contains two conditions:

```
string searchx = "some string"; 

if ((searchx.Contains("a1")) || (searchx.Contains("a2")))
{
...
}
```

But how to get  list of values with single variable for statement?

If I got `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9...`

Can I  do it somehow this way, seems it is wrong attempt:

```
var valueList = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
```

But just to explain what I want to do, so if any value exist under `valueList`, condition is accepted:

```
if (searchx.Contains(valueList)) 
{
...
}
```

The best if I can get multiple value return I guess or any other way to get statement with updated list of values through single variable of any other way, which can work for me this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has worked for me:

```
if (valueList.Any(x => searchx.Contains(x)))
{
}
```

or even shorter (thanks to rajeeshmenoth)

```
    if(valueList.Any(searchx.Contains))
```

Comment: You can try this one also : valueList.Any(searchx.Contains);

Comment: @Philipp Schmid yes this one works very well I guess , what the difference between `(valueList.Any(x => searchx.Contains(x)))` and `(valueList.Any(searchx.Contains))` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally pressed enter way too early. `Any` checks every item in valueList and returns true if one function/condition in the brackets returns true (in this case `searchx.Contains(x)`, with `x` being just a name for the current list item). It returns false as soon as there are no more elements left to check. I think the compiler is just intelligent enough to add an arbitrary variable name to the more simple conditions.

Comment: @PhilippSchmid Welocme :)

Comment: @Philipp Schmid now is clear, both variants very useful for this case as with x if I can attach it to different value with  temporarily  taken name for some reason  and also variant  by (rajeeshmenoth) simply to do multi statement condition

Answer (score 3):

You can try and use `Except`

```
if (valueList.Except(searchx).Any())
{

}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I guess that returns `false ` if searchx=="a1", while the original version returns true.

Comment: @BernhardHiller Actually this does return nothing, because it doesn't compile :)

Comment: @David Pilkington not sure if I'm using this solution correctly, seems something is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution, but works.

```
bool containsValue(string search)
{
var valueList = new List<string> { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};
foreach (string s in valueList)
 {
 if(search.Contains(s))
  return true;
 }
return false;
}
```

and use it like :

```
if (containsValue(searchx))
{
... do something ...
}
```

Comment: You could probably do it in one line, but in our dev environment we were told not to be too "smart", so we try to make all code as simple as possible, just so any other dev can understand code without spending unnecessary time figuring out "why" it was done like this. E.g. Philipp's solution would also work, and it's way more "elegant".

Comment: @Vytautas Plečkaitis yes got it, also can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq :

```
  bool b = valueList.Any(searchx.Contains);
```

Try this :

```
    string searchx = "a8"; 
    var valueList = new List<string>{"a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"};

    if (valueList.Any(searchx.Contains))
        Console.WriteLine("Data Matching..!!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Matching..!!");
```

**Demo :**[Click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4GHeLw)

Comment: If searchx = "somea1string", it should return data match

Comment: @viktor80 Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can make a foreach loop

```
string search = "GIVE A STRING";
List<string> DataList = new List<string> {"a1", "a2", "a3",.....};
foreach(string Data in DataList)
{ 
  if(search.Contains(Data))
  { //TODO }
}
```